# Sql query to find users who opened emails between 2nd and 5th day after email is sent

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have table something like this.sample data

```
+----------------------------+---------------------------+---------+----------+
|id                          |email                      |event    |timestamp |
+----------------------------+---------------------------+---------+----------+
|take-2-blazin-it-safe-us-can|1297323246@yahoo.com       |processed|1584974510|
|take-2-blazin-it-safe-us-can|1297323246@yahoo.com         |delivered|1584974513|
|take-2-blazin-it-safe-us-can|1297323246@yahoo.com       |open     |1584978453|
|take-2-blazin-it-safe-us-can|1297323246@yahoo.com     |open     |1584983574|
|take-2-blazin-it-safe-us-can|1297323246@yahoo.com        |open     |1584983578|
+----------------------------+---------------------------+---------+----------+
```

i want no users who opened emails between 2-5 days after email is delivered. Ex : If the email is sent 21st then, of users who opened email between 23rd and 26th including both 23rd and 26th.

So far i have tried like this

```
with tab as(
  select  distinct * from table
  where event in ('delivered','open')
  )
select count(case when last_val - first_val between 2 and 5 then 1 else 0 ) from(
select *, first_value(from_unixtime(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd') over(partition by id,email order by timestamp asc) as first_val,
last_value(from_unixtime(timestamp,'yyyy-MM-dd') over(partition by id,email order by timestamp asc) last_val from tab

)
```

But this will work only if user has opened email once, but there are cases where user opened the email more than once. Those count should also be included.

Is there any clean way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use aggregation, but first get the delivered timestamp.  The following just uses timestamp arithmetic, rather than converting to date/time values:

```
select id, email
from (select t.*,
             min(timestamp) filter (where event = 'delivered') over (partition by id, email) as delivered_timestamp
      from t
     ) t
where event = 'open'
group by id, email
having count(*) filter (where timetamp >= delivered_timestamp + 2*24*60*60 and
                              timestamp < delivered_timestamp + 6*24*60*60
                       ) > 0;
```

Another method is `exists`:

```
select t.*
from t
where t.event = 'delivered' and
      exists (select 1
              from t t2
              where t2.id = t.tid and t2.email = t.email and
                    t2.timestamp >= t.timestamp + 2*24*6*60 and
                    t2.timestamp < t.timestamp + 6*24*6*60
             );
```

Comment: Thanks, it will really work, but what if we want users who opened after 10 days also in same query, Do we have to write separate query

Comment: @MaheshKalani . . . (1) This answers the question that you asked here.  (2) There are several options in this answer, some of them can be adopted to multiple timeframes.

Comment: ```range between 2*24*60*60 following and 6*24*60*60 - 1 following``` this doesnt work with posgressql. gives error SYNTAX_ERROR: line 4:19: Window frame RANGE FOLLOWING is only supported with UNBOUNDED

Comment: @yahoo . . . I removed that option.  I forget that Postgres doesn't fully implement the standard functionality -- normally, it is pretty consistent with standard SQL.